# What is the difference between testng annotation @Beforemethod and beforeinvocation() listener?

Tags: annotations, testng, listener

> Does @Beforemethod() and beforeInvocation() listener do the same? Please help with the difference!

Answer (score 0):

`@Beforemethod`: The annotated method will be run before each test method  meaning Methods annotated with @Test annotation

If you have implemented the `IInvokedMethodListener` listener

```
void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult)
void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method,ITestResult testResult)
```

then IInvokedMethodListener  will be invoked for configuration(@BeforeSuite...) and test methods (@Test ...).

Comment: will IInvokedMethodListener be executed even before @BeforeSuite?

Answer (score 0):

From an execution stage perspective, both get executed before a method annotated with @Test is called.  It allows you to do any kind of setup you need for a test.

But when do you use what will be based on what is it you want to do.

If you have a specific setup for only a few tests, I will use @BeforeMethod in a class which would apply only to a few tests.
But if it is an suite wide setup, say initializing a driver object or creating an API token which needs to be done for every single test in your suite, then I would prefer listeners.

Comment: @BeforeMethod will be executed for all methods right?

Comment: if the class containing the method is part of execution or parent class